# PHP: Extract value from JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an API that takes parameters from a post through JSON and I want to extract one of the values in an array for a key value pair.  However, despite many attempts, I can't get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$request = json_decode($json, true);
$parameters = $request["result"]["parameters"];
```

When I log `$parameters` to a text file, it log as

```
 {"numberofhits":"5"}
```

However, my efforts to capture the value 5 are not working:

```
$numhits = $json['numberofhits']; logs as empty.
```

So does:

```
$numhits = $parameters->numberofhits;
```

How can I capture the value 5 in a variable?

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump()` the `$parameters` variable?

Comment: according to your code `$json` is just a string from a file. No way `$json['numberofhits']` will work

Comment: @adjan He might have made a typo asking the question. The `$parameters->numberofhits` *should* have worked just fine. Something doesn't add up.

Comment: Not sure how to var_dump in this case.  To see output I have to log to text file as input is coming from a third party.

Comment: if your data is being posted, i think php will take ur json and serialize it to the $_POST array global variable. $numHits = $_POST['result']['parameters']

Comment: I'm not sure what that means "coming from a third party" -- you have no way of testing?

Comment: `$numhits = $parameters->numberofhits;` will never work. Since you've decoded it to an array (second parameter of `json_decode` set to `true`) there will be no objects that you can access with `->`.

Comment: What I mean is the other website is sending quite a lot of JSON. The output from those requests goes back to the website not to my browser window.  I'll try logging var_dump and see what it shows.

Answer (score 1):

From your code above `$json` is a string and not a json object, your should use `$request` to access numberofhits

```
$request['numberofhits']
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `$parameters` just shows `{"numberofhits":"5"}`, this means your post request just returned a json of a json. Try json decoding `$parameters` again like `json_decode($parameters, true);` and log that result. It should log the desired array.

Comment: When I log that it is empty.

Comment: Are you sure your $parameters just shows {"numberofhits":"5"}? Coz if it does, the above should work just fine.