# php: Extract value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array stored in a variable--at least I think it is an array--and want to get a value from it.

This is what the `$myvar` logs as and why I think it is an array:

```
Array
(
    [numberofhits] => 5
)
```

How can I get the value 5 into a variable?

Have tried some likely possibilities such as

```
 $numhits = $myvar->numberofhits;

But $numhits is empty.
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: $numhits = $myvar['numberofhits'];

Comment: You already asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922830/php-extract-value-from-json-array

Comment: As you said, its an array, not an object, so you have to access trough $var['elem'] insteadof $var->elem

Comment: Optionally, you can cast the array to an object by doing `$myvar = (object)$myvar;` but that is overkill for what you're trying to do...

Comment: The previous question asked about working with a JSON array. Since JSON was a complicating factor and did not yield an answer that worked, I I asked a new question about an regular array--no mention of JSON.  Regular arrays and JSON are quite different.  The two questions are not identical.

Comment: They're essentially the same. After you do `json_decode()` it's just a PHP object or array, and you use the same syntax to access the contents.